# Is it possible to create SharePoint calendars templates in SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to create SharePoint calendars templates in SharePoint 2019? I am trying to create a template from a calendar in the modern experience and is not working. The import comes from excel and I have tried to import the data on a csv format and neither.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the calendar template in SharePoint 2019? Did you import data from excel? Could you please provide more details about the issue?

Per my test in my SharePoint 2019 environment, I can create the calendar template and create the calendar from the template. It can work.